# react-responsive-carousel is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on an online ecommerce website using react js. On the details page for every product, I am using react-responsive-carousel to allow the user to slide through all images for that specific product. I also wanted there to be thumbnails underneath that are also selectable. react-responsive-carousel was a perfect choice because it was easy to implement and the look/functionality was almost exactly how I wanted it to look. Initially, everything was working fine, but for some reason the carousel stopped displaying properly. My code involving the carousel is the same as it was before, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

This is how the images are displaying now:

[Top view of the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euNxF.jpg)
[Lower view of the carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cNwm.jpg)

As you can see, the images are stacked on top of each other, as well as the thumbnails. The next/previous buttons are in the wrong spot and each image is prepended with a bullet point.

This is my code for the entire product details page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {ProductConsumer} from '../context.js';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import SizeSelector from './SizeSelector.js';
import {Carousel} from 'react-responsive-carousel';

export default class Details extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <ProductConsumer>
            {value => {
                const {id, title, img, info, price, size} = value.detailProduct;

                const images = img.map(index =>
                    <div>
                        <img className="img-fluid" key={id} src={index} alt="Product"/>
                    </div>
            );
                
                return (
                    <div className="mx-2 pb-5">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-10 mx-auto text-center my-5">
                                <h1>{title}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 mb-3">
                                <Carousel>{images}</Carousel>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 mb-3">
                                <h3 className="mb-2">${price}</h3>
                                <p className="mb-5">{info}</p>
                                <SizeSelector />
                                <Link to="/products">
                                    <button className="btn btn-black mr-5">Back to products</button>
                                </Link>
                                <span className="btn btn-black" 
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        if (value.size === "")
                                        {
                                            value.openSizePrompt();
                                        }
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            value.addToCart(id, value.size);
                                            value.openModal(id, value.size);
                                        }
                                }}>
                                    Add to cart
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }}
        </ProductConsumer>
    )
}
}
```

Also, I have a javascript file containing the product data. When a storeProduct is selected, the values of the product are set to a detailProduct. From there, I can get all of the data about that product. 'img' is the object containing the array of images. Each product may have a different amount of images (usually 2-4), so I have to dynamically create the `<div> <img/> </div>` using the `img.map` function.

If anyone has a clue on how to fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate the help. I really do not want to go through the effort of implementing my own carousel. I am more than happy to provide other information that may help fix the problem.

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem with a simple import:

`import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css'`

However, before I ran into this issue, everything was displaying fine without this import. I am not sure what changed that required me to do this.

Comment: I am still facing the issue , any other resolution to it ?

Answer (score 0):

**This is working for me!**

check this - [Swipeable not working on mobile](https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/issues/577#issue-833810579)

```
import React from "react";

// requires a loader
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; 

const settings = {
  showArrows: false,
  interval: 3500,
  dynamicHeight: false,
  stopOnHover: false,
  infiniteLoop: true,
  showStatus: false,
  transitionTime: 500,
  showThumbs: false,
  showIndicators: true,
  swipeable: true,
  emulateTouch: true,
  autoPlay: true,
};

const TestimonialsCarousel = ({ testimonials }, featured) => (
  <Carousel {...settings}>
    {testimonials
      .filter((item) => (item.featured || !featured) == true)
      .map((item) => (
        <div key={item.quote}>
          <div className="has-text-left has-text-white is-size-6 is-family-secondary px-xxs">
            <blockquote>{item.quote}</blockquote>
          </div>
          <div className="has-text-left has-text-white has-text-weight-medium testimonialauthor pt-small px-xxs">
            <p>—{item.author}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
  </Carousel>
);

export default TestimonialsCarousel;
```